# JMS - Weblogic maximum connected listeners

Tags: java, jms, weblogic12c

Currently I am working on application which is listening to the queues on weblogic (12c).

In my app I have configured several concurrent beans which are listening to the one queue (Let it be 10 beans). All of this beans are listening to this one queue, this is verified by the logs that I am seeing.

The problem is that whenever batch insert is about sending 10k messages or 100k only 3 to 4 beans are used and no more I know this by checking the logs of threads that are used.

I tought that it might be something with weblogic configuration where there is any restriction on this?

Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of beans did you deploy to consume jms messages ?

Comment: These are classes that are implementing MessageListener